# XSL transform of nested XML

Tags: xslt

I'm new to the world of XSLT. I have found a couple of threads on here that have helped but as I don't really understand what I'm doing I'm a bit stuck. I am trying to loop through and format some nested XML.

My XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<exchange>
<vco>
<vco.srs>
<vco_crsc.vco.srs>BUUBMS</vco_crsc.vco.srs>
<vco_prgc.vco.srs>BUBSBAT02</vco_prgc.vco.srs>
<vco_rouc.vco.srs>USMANG</vco_rouc.vco.srs>
<cbo>
<cbo.srs>
<cbo_occl.cbo.srs>AJ</cbo_occl.cbo.srs>
</cbo.srs>
<cbo.srs>
<cbo_occl.cbo.srs>FJ</cbo_occl.cbo.srs>
</cbo.srs>
</cbo>
</vco.srs>
</vco>
</exchange>
```

From reading another similar post I have created a template based bit of code . The template functions but ideally I would want it formatted differently as I'm losing the field formatting due to the templates. Presume I need another template defining but as I said, not really sure what I am doing!

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
<xsl:template match="/root">
<ImportTask>
<xsl:apply-templates select="CourseDetails"/>-<xsl:apply-templates select="CourseOcc"/>
</ImportTask>       
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CourseDetails">
<Courses>
<xsl:for-each select="exchange/vco/vco.srs">
<Course>
<CourseCode><xsl:value-of select="vco_crsc.vco.srs"/></CourseCode>-<Programmecode><xsl:value-of select="vco_prgc.vco.srs"/></Programmecode>-<Routecode><xsl:value-of select="vco_rouc.vco.srs"/></Routecode>
</Course>
</xsl:for-each>
</Courses>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="CourseOcc">
<Occurences>
<xsl:for-each select="exchange/cbo/cbo.srs">
<Occur>
<OccurCode><xsl:value-of select="cbo_occl.cbo.srs"/></OccurCode>
</Occur>
</xsl:for-each>
</Occurences>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is outputting:

```
BUUBMS
BUBSBAT02
USMANG


AJ


FJ
```

Which is all very nice but not what I want.
Ideally I would like the output to be:

```
    <ImportTask>
    <Courses>
    <Course>BUUBMS-BUBSBAT02-USMANG-AJ</Course>
    <Course>BUUBMS-BUBSBAT02-USMANG-FJ<Course>
    </Courses>
   </ImportTask>
```

I'm guessing I need more template code set up but I'm not sure exactly what?

Can someone point me in the right direction or tell me if there is a better way?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following xslt transfers your input to the desired output. There, only two templates are used, one for the root-element, one for `<cbo_occl.cbo.srs>`. The latter selects the text-nodes of the elements starting with "vco_" before that element, concats them and finally prints its own content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="/exchange">
        <ImportTask>
            <Courses>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//cbo_occl.cbo.srs"/>
            </Courses>
        </ImportTask>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cbo_occl.cbo.srs">
        <Course>
            <!-- select all text-Nodes of vco_* elements -->
            <xsl:for-each select="../../../*[matches(name(),'^vco_.*')]/text()">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,'-')"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </Course>        
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Leu! That's perfect.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand all the syntax but I can look it up and work backwards for the bit: <xsl:for-each select="../../../*[matches(name(),'^vco_.*')]/text()">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,'-')"/>

Comment: So I guess the next question is if my XML was nested further, say there was another entity that sat below the CBO level and I wanted individual values from that entity ,  would I then need another template, and would that template sit in the first section:  

        <xsl:template match="/exchange">
        <ImportTask>
            <Courses>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//cbo_occl.cbo.srs"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//anothertemplate"/>
               </Courses>
              </ImportTask>
        </xsl:template>

Comment: I propose to ask another question where you link to this one and where your new input-XML is better readable than in comments. There, you can be more specific what needs to be refined.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of different template matches in your XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="/root">

<xsl:template match="CourseDetails">

<xsl:template match="CourseOcc">
```

However, when you use a template with a match, these only apply when they match nodes in your input XML document. You cannot just use arbitrary names here. Because your input XML does not have elements called `root`, `CourseDetails` or `CourseOcc`, then these templates never get called.

The reason you are getting the output you are currently getting is because of XSLT's [built-in template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule) rules, which apply when there are no matching templates for a node in your own XSLT (which is the case here).

What I think you were trying to do, is actually achieved with "named" templates, which would allow you to use arbitrary names. So, your XSLT would be more properly written like so:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <ImportTask>
        <xsl:call-template name="CourseDetails"/>
        <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
        <xsl:call-template name="CourseOcc"/>
    </ImportTask>       
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="CourseDetails">
    <Courses>
        <xsl:for-each select="exchange/vco/vco.srs">
            <Course>
                <CourseCode><xsl:value-of select="vco_crsc.vco.srs"/></CourseCode>
                <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
                <Programmecode><xsl:value-of select="vco_prgc.vco.srs"/></Programmecode>
                <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
                <Routecode><xsl:value-of select="vco_rouc.vco.srs"/></Routecode>
            </Course>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Courses>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="CourseOcc">
    <Occurences>
        <xsl:for-each select="exchange/cbo/cbo.srs">
            <Occur>
                <OccurCode><xsl:value-of select="cbo_occl.cbo.srs"/></OccurCode>
            </Occur>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Occurences>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note how the first template is still a template match, but one that matches `/` and not `/root`, where `/` represents the "document node". This is the template that will get matched first by XSLT.

Having said that, you don't actually need to use named templates here. You can achieve what you want with normal template matching. This XSLT would probably be preferable in this case

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>

<xsl:template match="/exchange">
    <ImportTask>
        <Courses>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="vco/vco.srs"/>
        </Courses>
        <xsl:if test="cbo/cbo.srs">
            <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
            <Occurences>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="cbo/cbo.srs"/>
            </Occurences>
        </xsl:if>
    </ImportTask>       
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="vco.srs">
    <Course>
        <CourseCode><xsl:value-of select="vco_crsc.vco.srs"/></CourseCode>
        <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
        <Programmecode><xsl:value-of select="vco_prgc.vco.srs"/></Programmecode>
        <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
        <Routecode><xsl:value-of select="vco_rouc.vco.srs"/></Routecode>
    </Course>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cbo.srs">
    <Occur>
        <OccurCode><xsl:value-of select="cbo_occl.cbo.srs"/></OccurCode>
    </Occur>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Tim
Thanks for looking at this. You have done a very good explanation of what I did not really understand. I think I can see where I have gone wrong and missed out bit that were needed.